# Best way to find matching unfiltered string from match substring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a program that is matching phone numbers from a very large list as the user types.  The phone numbers in the list as well as the string the user is typing could be in any format, like (206)-555-1212 or 206-555-1212 or even +12065551212.

I am testing for a match by stripping out non-decimal digits, like:

`sourceStr.replace(/\D/g, '').indexOf(matchStr.replace(/\D/g, '')`

This works fine.

Now I want to highlight the portion of the source string that matched, like make the background color yellow.  So if the phone number is "+1 206-555-1212" and the person typed "(206)55", I want to highlight just that 20655 part, like "+1 **206-55**5-1212".

What is the best way to find the START and END of the portion of the match, so that I know what part to highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept. The idea is to perform the check by hand so you can figure out where the actual indices are. Then, you can make a span from the start-end range once you find it. I assume all of your text is within a single text node.

```js
const getMatchPositions = (text, target) => {
  target = target.replace(/\D/g, '');
  const positions = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] !== target[0]) {
      continue;
    }
    
    const start = i;

    for (let j = i, k = 0; 
           j < text.length && k < target.length; j++) {
      if (/\d/.test(text[j])) {
        if (text[j] !== target[k]) {
          break;
        }
        else if (k >= target.length - 1) {
          positions.push([start, j + 1]);
          i = j;
          break;
        }
      
        k++;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return positions;
};

const highlightPositions = (textEl, positions) =>
  positions.slice().reverse().forEach(([start, end]) => {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textEl.firstChild, start);
    range.setEnd(textEl.firstChild, end);
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.background = "#0f6";
    range.surroundContents(span);
  })
;

const originalTextEl = document.querySelector("p");
const textEl = originalTextEl.cloneNode(true);
const text = originalTextEl.textContent;

const handleChange = value => {
  const positions = getMatchPositions(text, value);
  const textEl2 = textEl.cloneNode(true);
  highlightPositions(textEl2, positions);
  originalTextEl.innerHTML = textEl2.innerHTML;
};

const inputEl = document.querySelector("input");
inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  handleChange(e.target.value);
});
handleChange(inputEl.value);
```

```html
<input value="(206)55">
<p>
  foo bar (206)-555-1212 or 206-555-1212 or even +12065551212. or +1 206-555-1212
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing it by hand but was wondering if there was anything smarter...  perhaps there isn't.